# Does anyone know in Python how to pass a variable to another function to be used without running the actual function?

Tags: python, variables, kivy, textinput

I am new to coding so bear with me. I have function A that is passing the variable x to function B. I don't want function B to run when I pass the variable, rather just be able to access variable x when needed. Basically I have kivy text input on my KV file that when the button is clicked it then executes function B. If I were to run function B in function A the user does not get the chance to input text.

**PY FILE**

```
def A():
    x = 1
    B(x)

def B(x):
     print(x)
     print(kivy.textinput.text)
```

**KV FILE:**

```
on_press: root.B()
```

Comment: Why not call `A()` from `B()` instead and have `A()` return the value? If A() just declares a variable, then is it actually needed since you can just declare the variable in B()?

Comment: `lambda: B(x)` or `functools.partial(B, x)` will give you a parameterless function that calls `B` with one pre-specified parameter when it is invoked - is that what you're asking for?

Comment: I think python classes will work for you well here. x will be a class variable and the two methods will be able to access each other and x

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def call_b(self):
        B(self.x)


c = MyClass(1)

on_press: c.call_b()
```